# setVisible (true) not showing until page refreshed

Tags: java, wicket

I have my string variable I want to display

`final String wrongPw = "Wrong Password";`

My AJAX yes button:

```
AjaxButton yesButton = new AjaxButton("yesButton", yesNoForm) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3827487963204274386L;
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
            if (target != null && password.equals(getPw())) {
                answer.setAnswer(true);
                modalWindow.close(target);
            }else if(target != null && !password.equals(getPw())){
                answer.setAnswer(false);
                wrongPW.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    };
```

Further down:

```
wrongPW.setVisible(false);
add(wrongPW);
```

When I hit the yes button I must refresh the page for the `wrongPW` to display.

How can this be done dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the component you want to update to the target like this:

```
target.add(wrongPW);
```

Be sure to set the markup placeholder tag on initialization of the component you want to dynamically change the visibility of, else Wicket won't find it.

```
wrongPW.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

The reasons for this are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671796/2795423

Comment: ah bingo, i was just using `setOutputMarkupId(true);` - thanks